# Contact form cannot work well on specific email

Tags: contacts

I am facing a problem for my form.
It cannot receive well when i set abc@xxxx.co.id as receiver. All message is correct, just it will stat with "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 " and come with table format.
It should look tidy.

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
To: crm@merekmu.co.id
From: <hl.tam@webnic.cc>
Message-Id: <20130618031715.7DA4712406D9@gemilang-pandi.localdomain>
Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2013 10:17:15 +0700 (WIT)


<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Merekmu “LIKE and WIN” Contest Submission</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <h2>Merekmu “LIKE and WIN” Contest Submission</h2> 
 <table width='95%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='11'>
```

However, this form work well if i use another email as receiver(123@xxxx.com). Use same code, i just change email.

I made some testing as below:

email 1:abc@xxxx.co.id
email 2:123@xxxx.com
web 1:www.456.com
web 2:www.abc.co.id

Test 1: set email abc@xxxx.co.id as receiver at www.abc.co.id - messy message receive
Test 2: set email 123@xxxx.com as receiber at www.abc.co.id - work well and show tidy  message
Test 3: set email abc@xxxx.co.id as receiver at www.456.com - work well and show tidy  message

I have no idea with what problem is it?

```
<?php 

$firstName= $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName= $_POST['lastName'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$fbUrl= $_POST['fbUrl'];
$blog= $_POST['blog'];




// subject
$subject = $name;

// message
$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Merekmu “LIKE and WIN” Contest Submission</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Merekmu “LIKE and WIN” Contest Submission</h2>
 <table width='95%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='11'>
    <tr>
      <td width='189'> First Name:</td>
      <td>$firstName</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width='189'> Last Name:</td>
      <td>$lastName</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width='189'> Email:</td>
      <td>$email</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width='189'> Facebook profile URL:</td>
      <td>$fbUrl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width='189'> Blog:</td>
      <td>$blog</td>
    </tr>



    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
</html>
";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= "To:crm@merekmu.co.id" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$name."<".$email.">\r\n";
$subject .= "Merekmu “LIKE and WIN” Contest Submission ";
//$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";


if(mail($toemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '';
}

?>
```

valindation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#contactForm').submit(function() {
        $('form#contactForm .error').remove();
        var hasError = false;
        $('.requiredField').each(function() {
            if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                $(this).parent().append('<div class="error">Lapangan tidak boleh kosong.</div>');
                hasError = true;
            } else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if(!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).parent().append('<div class="error">Silakan masukkan email yang valid.</div>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
        });

        if(!hasError) {
            $('form#contactForm li.submit_btn').fadeOut('normal', function() {
                $(this).parent().append('<img src="/wp-content/themes/td-v3/images/template/loading.gif" alt="Loading&hellip;" height="31" width="31" />');
            });
            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
                $('form#contactForm').slideUp("fast", function() {                 
                    $(this).before('<p class="thanks">Formulir telah dikirimkan.</p>');
                });
            });
        }

        return false;

    });
});
```

HTML

```
 <form action="submit.php" id="contactForm" method="post">

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <td valign="top" colspan="2" align="center"> <div class="title"> Merekmu “LIKE and WIN” Contest Submission </div></td>


  </tr>
      <tr>
       <td valign="top" width="200" class="form-left"><label for="contactName"><strong>First Name:</strong> <span class="require">*</span></label></td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" class="requiredField" /></td>

  </tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="form-left"><label for="contactName"><strong>Last Name:</strong> <span class="require">*</span></label></td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" class="requiredField" /></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td valign="top" class="form-left"><label for="email"><strong>Email:</strong> <span class="require">*</span></label></td>
   <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="requiredField email" /></td>
 </tr>


  <tr>
  <td valign="top" class="form-left"><label for="tel"><strong>Facebook profile URL:</strong> <span class="require">*</span></label>
        </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="fbUrl" id="fbUrl" value="" class="requiredField" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td valign="top" class="form-left"><label for="tel"><strong>Blog:</strong> </label>
        </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="blog" id="blog" value="" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td valign="top" colspan="2" align="center"> <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />   
        </td>

  </tr>



</table>

</form>
```